# Does using the Random class "unnecessarily complicate" things?

Tags: java, math, random

I handed in an assignment recently, for my Computer Science course. In it I used the Random classover the Math.random() method in order to generate random numbers. My lecturer marked me down for this, stating that it was an "unnecessary complication" and that I should avoid importing classes when not absolutely needed.

I've nothing against her for this, and I accept that this is her preferred method that does have it's merits, but I would appreciate the opinion of a wider (perhaps more experienced) group- since Math.random() calls the Random class anyway and (afaik) creates a new Random object each time the method is called, wouldn't it make sense to just cut out the middleman?

Thanks

Comment: only a person who have never used it before might say so

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. What was the actual task?

Comment: @Andy I think in this instance it was generating randomly sized objects on a GUI- so the random numbers were used for sides, dimensions and colours. Reasonable simple

Comment: Since `Math.random` is essentially equivalent to creating a `new Random()` and then calling `random.nextDouble()`, I don't see why your lecturer thinks it is an issue...

Comment: Did she suggest an alternative? The only thing that I can think about using a static method like `Math.random()` is that it makes it hard to test deterministically - vs injecting a `Random` instance. But dependency injection like that can also be perceived as "unnecessary complication".

Comment: Ask your professor when was the last time they wrote code for money.  What a silly comment.  You shouldn't create a Random every time the method is called.  It ought to be a class member that you can see on construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Math.random()` does use `Random`, but it uses a single instance.
However since `Math.random()` is equivalent to `Random.nextDouble();` which is usually not very useful, it would be foolish to use it instead of the `Random` class, which has plenty of convenience methods that make your intention clear and bugs less likely, as demonstrated in the following snippet.

```
int x = (int)(Math.random() * 100);  // Without parentheses you'll always get 0
int y = rnd.nextInt(100);
```

I suspect your lecturer has a strong *theoretical* knowledge about programming.

Comment: Good point on readability

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that your instructor is flat-out wrong.  Maintainability should be one of your primary goals, and reproducibility is essential to debugging and maintainability.  `Math.random()` gives you no control over the seeding, and consequently no reproducibility if something weird is noted during testing and debugging.

Answer (score -1):

I would not be surprised if this question became closed for being too subjective.
But anyway -

I would say this depends on the context. Did your 'mistake' of using Random cause bad perfomance, unreadable code, or anything at all? If not, then I think it is fine.

One can nitpick about these kind of things, but in reality - in my opinion at least - there are larger things to worry about than such theoretical problems.